# Why is the result equal to 0 and sometimes 1 - shell_exec('pgrep -f

Tags: php, bash, grep, shell-exec

The script:

```
$S = 'pgrep -f test.php | wc -l';
$U = trim(shell_exec($S));
echo $U;
```

Why is the result of this script equal to `0` and sometimes `1` ?

The file `test.php` is not running.

Comment: because grepping is also a new process, you need to filter grep process from the results. With ps aux you can do: `ps aux | grep test.php | grep -v grep | wc -l`

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas This also works with other commands, piping the result - whichever it might be - to `grep -v pgrep` is a negation which says: "everything **except** what is specified via the `-v` flag".

Comment: See [How can I prevent 'grep' from showing up in ps results?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is while executing the command `pgrep -f test.php | wc -l`, it will show up itself sometimes (depending on the timing) in the results. You can prevent that according to [a question on Linux & Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74186) using the following syntax:

```
pgrep -f '[t]est.php' | wc -l
```

The part with the brackets basically says "find the letter **t** followed by **est.php**", which will find the file if it is running, but will not match the currently executed command, because after the `t` follows a bracket `[`.